# How to hook a UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell's init method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

We use UITableViewCell like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName: Cell bundle: nil] forCellReuseIdentifier: kIdentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: kIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

When cells are born with some properties(tag), how to get cell's `- init` method, customize it, and tag the cell?

As I did not see any chance while calling the relative methods.

So how to hook a UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell's `init` method?

Here is a situation:

[image: img]

There are two pages. The cell has a page tag.

Sure, I can add property. Just go a litter farther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a simple subclass of `UITableViewCell`. This way you can create customized table cells with whatever you would like the cell to contain "during" the initialization of the cell. Then you could set your nib file class to, for this example, `CustomTableViewCell`.

Then, like you already have shown, you can just create your customized cells from your `reuseIdentifier`:

Additionally, you can intercept the other built in methods `awakeFromNib` and even `prepareForReuse` for further customization.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: kIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    // Do anything else here you would like. 
    // [cell someCustomMethod];

    return cell;
}
```

#### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

- (void)someCustomMethod;
...
@property (nonatomic, nullable) <Some class you want> *somePropertyName;
...
@end
```

#### .m

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Do whatever you would like to do here :)
    }

    return self;

}

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Initialization code. Do whatever you like here as well :)

}

- (void)prepareForReuse {

    [super prepareForReuse];

    // And here.. :)

}

@end
```

Comment: After all, UITableViewCell is a kind of class. So how to intercept it from the beginning. Any clues?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean :\ maybe try explaining a little more?

Comment: `Class * object = [[ Class alloc ] init];` , UITableViewCell is Class, which is inherited from UIView. Apple did a lot thing for us. So we did not know how it happens. In my opinion,  the process exists. I am wondering is there some way to handle. I do not know much under the hood, So I ask

Comment: Like @Gereon mentions, there is really **no** benefit / reason to need to "intercept" the creation of the base object for a class... from the approach I have posted you should more than be able to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`init` isn't really helpful, since cells are created only rarely and then reused.

That said, when cells are initially created, you can intercept that by overloading `awakeFromNib`. When they're reused later, `prepareForReuse` is called.

Don't forget to call the super implementations in both methods.